# Problem 3-26 in Spivak´s Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, integration, manifolds

Let $ f: [a,b] \to \mathbf{R}$ be integrable and non-negative and let 
$$ A_f = \{ (x,y) : a \leq x \leq b \mbox{ and  } 0 \leq y \leq f(x)\}$$
Show that $A_f$ is Jordanmeasurable
and has area $ \int_a^b f$.

What I have done is that, $A_f$ is Jordan measurable if $\int_s1$ exists. Then for some rectangle $Q$ containing $S$,

$\int_s1=\int_Q1_s$. Where $1_s$ is a characteristic function defined by $1_s(x) =    \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                {1} & \mbox{x $\in$ S};\\
              {0}  & \mbox{x $\not\in S$}.\end{array} \right. $

So now our aim is to show that $\int_Q1_s$ exists. This happens $\mathbf{iff}$ set of discontinuities of $1_s$ in $Q$ is of measure $0$, and this set of discontinuities is just discontinuities of $f$ in $Q$(because $1_s$ continuous everywhere else in $Q$).

Hence now I just need to show that discontinuities of $f$ is of measure $0$ in $R^2$.

Comment: @Agustí Roig: I edited the problem with the things that I've tried. Now I am facing problem in finding cover for $f$ in $R^2$ such that the summation of volumes of rectangles is less than $\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are referring to Jordan measurability I'm assuming that Riemann integrability of $f$ is meant.

Given an $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition
$$a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_N=b$$
of $[a,b]$ into finitely many subintervals $I_k:=[x_{k-1},x_k]$ $\>(1\leq k\le N)$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \bigl(\overline{f_k}-\underline{f_k}\bigr)(x_k-x_{k-1})<\epsilon\ ,$$
where
$$\overline{f_k}:=\sup\nolimits_{x\in I_k} f(x),\quad \underline{f_k}:=\inf\nolimits_{x\in I_k} f(x)\ .$$
On the other hand, by definition of $A$ one has
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^N I_k\times[0,\underline{f_k}]\ \subset A\subset\ \bigcup_{k=1}^N I_k\times[0,\overline{f_k}]\ .$$
Here $A$ is squeezed between two finite unions of rectangles whose total area differs by less than $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary the claim follows.